# Lindo(Dofus-touch emulator) "npm-install error" node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`

Tags: node.js, npm, sass, npm-install, node-sass

I'm trying to build Lindo dofus touch [Lindo](https://github.com/prixe/lindo) whenever I try to do npm install it gives me an error. I've try to upgrade an downgrade my node-sass -v, and tried to install node js 12x. node didn't work. Anyone can try

```
$ git clone https://github.com/prixe/lindo.git
$ cd lindo
$ npm install
```

I also tried deleting and installing without "package-lock.json"

```
My versions:
Node v13.0.1
Npm v6.12.1
node-sass       4.13.0  (Wrapper)       [JavaScript]
libsass         3.5.4   (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]
```

here is my error log:

```
50999 verbose stack Error: node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
50999 verbose stack Exit status 1
50999 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\barisgun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
50999 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
50999 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\barisgun\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
50999 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
50999 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1028:16)
50999 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
51000 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.9.3
51001 verbose cwd C:\Users\barisgun\lindo
51002 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
51003 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\barisgun\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
51004 verbose node v13.0.1
51005 verbose npm  v6.12.1
51006 error code ELIFECYCLE
51007 error errno 1
51008 error node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
51008 error Exit status 1
51009 error Failed at the node-sass@4.9.3 postinstall script.
51009 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
51010 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Something in your dependency chain is trying to install node-sass 4.9.3, which isn't supported by Node 13. You'll need to find what that dependency is and see if there is a version that uses a node-sass 4.13.0 if you want to run Node 13.

Comment: Sir, in package.json I have this line "node-sass": "4.9.3", i have this line when I try to make it 4.13.0 it doesnt work and it says this node-sass is not suported. How can i change it ? is there any other way ?